# pd.concat turning categorical variables into object

Tags: pandas

I am seeing some strange behavior when trying to use `pd.concat`. I have a list of dataframes, with variables of one type (in this instance `categorical`) which get changed to `objects` when I concatenate them. The df is massive and this makes it even larger - too large to deal with.

Here is some sample code:
As context, I have scraped a website for a bunch of CSV files. I am reading, cleaning and setting the dtypes of all of them before appending them to a list. I then concatenate all the dfs in that list (but the dtypes of some variables get changed).

```
#Import modules
import glob
import pandas as pd

#Code to identify and download all the csvs
###
#code not included - seemed excessive
###

#Identify all the downloaded csvs        
modis_csv_files = glob.glob('/path/to/files/**/*.csv', recursive = True)

#Examine the dtypes of one of these files
pd.read_csv(modis_csv_files[0]).info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------      --------------  -----  
 0   latitude    6 non-null      float64
 1   longitude   6 non-null      float64
 2   brightness  6 non-null      float64
 3   scan        6 non-null      float64
 4   track       6 non-null      float64
 5   acq_date    6 non-null      object 
 6   acq_time    6 non-null      int64  
 7   satellite   6 non-null      object 
 8   instrument  6 non-null      object 
 9   confidence  6 non-null      int64  
 10  version     6 non-null      float64
 11  bright_t31  6 non-null      float64
 12  frp         6 non-null      float64
 13  daynight    6 non-null      object 
 14  type        6 non-null      int64  
dtypes: float64(8), int64(3), object(4)
memory usage: 848.0+ bytes
```

We can see a number of `object` dtypes in there that will make the final df larger. So now I try read all the files, and set the dtype as i go.

```
#Read the CSVs, clean them and append them to a list
outputs = [] #Create the list
counter = 1 #Start a counter as i am importing around 4000 files
for i in modis_csv_files: #Iterate over the files importing and cleaning
    print('Reading csv no. {} of {}'.format(counter, len(modis_csv_files))) #Produce a print statement describing progress
    output = pd.read_csv(i) #Read the csv
    output[['daynight', 'instrument', 'satellite']] = output[['daynight', 'instrument', 'satellite']].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category')) #Set the dtype for all the object variables that can be categories
    output['acq_date'] = output['acq_date'].astype('datetime64[ns]') #Set the date variable
    outputs.append(output) #Append to the list
    counter += 1 #Increment the counter

#Conetenate all the files
final_modis = pd.concat(outputs)

#Look at the dtypes
final_modis.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 85604183 entries, 0 to 24350
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column      Dtype         
---  ------      -----         
 0   latitude    float64       
 1   longitude   float64       
 2   brightness  float64       
 3   scan        float64       
 4   track       float64       
 5   acq_date    datetime64[ns]
 6   acq_time    int64         
 7   satellite   object        
 8   instrument  category      
 9   confidence  int64         
 10  version     float64       
 11  bright_t31  float64       
 12  frp         float64       
 13  daynight    object        
 14  type        int64         
dtypes: category(1), datetime64[ns](1), float64(8), int64(3), object(2)
memory usage: 9.6+ GB
```

Notice that `satellite` and `daynight` still show as `object` (though notably `instrument` stays as `category`). So I check if there is a problem with my cleaning code.

```
outputs[0].info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   latitude    6 non-null      float64       
 1   longitude   6 non-null      float64       
 2   brightness  6 non-null      float64       
 3   scan        6 non-null      float64       
 4   track       6 non-null      float64       
 5   acq_date    6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 6   acq_time    6 non-null      int64         
 7   satellite   6 non-null      category      
 8   instrument  6 non-null      category      
 9   confidence  6 non-null      int64         
 10  version     6 non-null      float64       
 11  bright_t31  6 non-null      float64       
 12  frp         6 non-null      float64       
 13  daynight    6 non-null      category      
 14  type        6 non-null      int64         
dtypes: category(3), datetime64[ns](1), float64(8), int64(3)
memory usage: 986.0 bytes
```

Looks like everything changed. Perhaps one of the 4000 dfs contained something that meant they could not be changed to `categorical`, which caused the whole variable to shift back to`object` when concatenated. Try checking each df in the list to see if either `satellite` or `daynight` is not `category`:

```
error_output = [] #create an empty list
for i in range(len(outputs)): #iterate over the list checking if dtype['variable'].name is categorical
    if outputs[i].dtypes['satellite'].name != 'category' or outputs[i].dtypes['daynight'].name != 'category':
        error_output.append(outputs[i]) #if not, append

#Check what is in the list
len(error_output)
0
```

So there are no dataframes in the list for which either of these variables is not `categorical`, but when I concatenate them the resulting variables are `objects`. Notably this outcome does not apply to all `categorical` variables, as `instrument` doesn't get changed back. What is going on?

Note: I can't change the dtype after `pd.concat`, because I run out of memory (I know there are some other solutions to this, but I am still intrigued by the behavior of `pd.concat`).

FWIW i am scraping data from the modis sattelite: https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/download/ (yearly summary by country). I can share all the scraping code as well if that would be helpful (seemed excessive for now however).

Comment: Why don't you concat first **then** convert the dtype? that'll be easier, and faster.

Comment: If I concat first, the resulting df is so massive that I can't do anything with it - including changing the dtype - without running out of memory.

Comment: Still, you can't simply concatenate `categorical` series since you might have new categories, and that changes the underlying `code` for categories. What's the point to have a big dataframe if you can't do anything with it? You may need more RAM :-)

Comment: My hope was that I could set the dtypes in such a way that I could get the df small enough to allow me to filter the df and end up with something small enough for me to do something with. Based on your comment, if I were to set the levels of all the categorical variables on a first df and then concact, would that resolve the problem of introducing new categories? I appreciate that I need more RAM - IT are not forthcoming...

Comment: You might be better just concatenate all the `csv` with Python, then load the big `csv` with pandas. Because the way you do now, you effectively use twice the memory needed for the whole data (once for the concat, once for the smaller dataframes).